# Is there a lightningd equivalent to bitcoind's -walletnotify or -blocknotify?

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning

I'm looking at the docs, and I see they have lightning-notifications, but it looks like you can't configure where they go, and you can't trigger a shell script with them. Does this mean I have to have all notifications sent to a shell script and filter them, or is there a method/configuration I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trigger a shell script with them, and more.
This is related to the plugin functionalities provided by `lightningd` and not `bitcoind`.

`lightningd` allows you to run [plugins](https://lightning.readthedocs.io/PLUGINS.html) to deeply modify its behaviour, or extend its possibilities. It idiomatically (small and robust core, customizable functionalities) relies a lot on them and therefore directed the event mechanisms toward them as well.
This is the reason why you don't see `[*]notify=` startup options for `lightningd`.

To use [`lightningd`'s notifications](https://lightning.readthedocs.io/PLUGINS.html#event-notifications) you have to write a plugin, but it can be a pretty simple script. For example, here is the handler of the `invoice_payment` notification in the [HelloWorld showcase plugin](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/master/contrib/plugins/helloworld.py):

```
@plugin.subscribe("invoice_payment")
def on_payment(plugin, invoice_payment, **kwargs):
    plugin.log("Received invoice_payment event for label {label}, preimage {preimage},"
               " and amount of {msat}".format(**invoice_payment))
```

The previous example used the Python library, but the communication is pretty straightforward (JSONRPC 2.0) so you can technically [use a shell script :-)](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/master/contrib/plugins/cowsay.sh).

For reference, there is an available and curated [list of community plugins](https://github.com/lightningd/plugins/#available-plugins).

Comment: Ah, I understand now. It's not there because the ability to add new functionality through plugins is instead.